# Xml Deserialization - Sequence of Mutiple Types

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Given the following fragment where links is a sequence of unbounded imagelinks and documentlinks, what should the deserailized class be?

```
<Values>
   <Links>
      <ImageLink>http://#</ImageLink>
      <ImageLink>http://#</ImageLink>
      <DocumentLink>http://#</DocumentLink>
   </Links>
</Values>
```

Typically, if it was just an array of imagelinks I might have

```
public class Values
{
   public imagelink[] ImageLinks { get; set; }
}

public class ImageLink
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

But with the above xml I'm stumped.

Btw, I have no control over the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked

```
public class DocumentLink : Link
{
}

public class ImageLink : Link
{
}

public class Link
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Href { get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ImageLink", Type = typeof(ImageLink))]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "DocumentLink", Type = typeof(DocumentLink))]
    public Link[] Links { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a base class Link as follows

```
public class Link
{
  public string Href { get; set; }
}

public class ImageLink : Link
{
}

public class DocumentLink : Link
{
}
```

And your values class would look like:

```
public class Values
{
   public Link[] links { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use ArrayList instead of strong typed array.

Comment: Not good enough. He'll also need explicit `[XmlElement]` declarations on `links` to let `XmlSerializer` know what derived types of `Link` are expected (and what the corresponding element names are).

Comment: It was intended to answer the question "what class should it be?", but you have a valid point that answers need to work. I'll leave it as is since Jaimal Chohan has already posted working code.

Comment: Cheers Bill and Pavel, although Bill's answer didn;t work, it did lead me in the right direction